# tkinter, message box close program on click "ok"

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I close the entire program once the user hits **OK** in the message box?

Here is the portion of the script that contains the button and command:

```
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def create_options(self):

        tk.Button(self,
                  text = "Begin search", command=self.pop_up1
                  ).place(x=465, y=285)

    def pop_up1(self):
        """shows submitted box"""
        tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Finished", message="Query Submitted")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by exit the entire program, you can close the window by using 
`self.root.destroy()` 
But depending on your implementation closing the window may not end your program but generally this is how you close a tkinter application. Just add it to the end of your button event.

Comment: Thanks! I used    
    self.destroy()    
and that did the trick.

Comment: Youre welcome, good luck with your project :)

Comment: @TheHoff remember to mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark off to the left there.

Comment: @WayneWerner Got it!